# Celery - How do I make a worker quit after it runs X number of tasks?

Tags: python, celery

I'd like to make a worker run for X number of tasks, and then quit. I can't find a way to do this. How can I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#std%3asetting-CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD):

> Maximum number of tasks a pool worker process can execute before it’s replaced with a new one. Default is no limit.

Comment: heh, how did I miss that? Sounds like that should do it. Thanks!